Problemas inserción datos tabla intermedia django
Estoy con un dilema de un proyecto de django, básicamente tengo una tabla con relación de muchos a muchos y automáticamente django me crea una tabla intermedia para administrar las relaciones. El dilema esta al cargar los datos por formulario por algún motivo no guarda las relaciones en la tabla intermedia, probé mediante el panel de administrador y guarda tranquilamente, solo no impacta con el formulario
Dejo algunas mas abajo un poco de mi código
#models.py

class ProductoForestal(models.Model):
    especie = models.ForeignKey(Especie, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    volumen = models.FloatField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.especie} - {self.producto}: {self.volumen}"
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Producto Forestal"
        verbose_name_plural = "Productos Forestales"

class Acta(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField()
    detalle = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    coordenada = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
    funcionario = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    deposito = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    depositario = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/%Y/%m/%d/",blank=True,null=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    numero = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    codigo = models.ForeignKey(Codigo, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey(Departamento, models.DO_NOTHING)
    distrito = models.ForeignKey(Distrito, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    localidad = models.ForeignKey(Localidad, models.DO_NOTHING)
    persona = models.ForeignKey(Persona, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    producto_forestal = models.ManyToManyField(ProductoForestal)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.descripcion
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Acta"
        verbose_name_plural = "Actas"

#views.py

@login_required
def formulario(request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    
    nombre = request.user.first_name +' '+ request.user.last_name
    grupo = request.user.groups.first().id
    codigo = Codigo.objects.filter(group_id=grupo).values()
    num = Acta.objects.filter(group_id=grupo).latest('numero').numero if Acta.objects.filter(group_id=grupo).exists() else 0

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ActaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            acta_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            acta_instance.codigo_id = codigo[0]['id']
            acta_instance.group_id = grupo
            acta_instance.numero = num + 1
            acta_instance.funcionario = nombre
            acta_instance.save()
        
            # Procesar múltiples valores para especie, producto y volumen
            especies = request.POST.getlist('especie')
            productos = request.POST.getlist('producto')
            volumenes = request.POST.getlist('volumen')

            # Iterar sobre los valores ingresados y crear instancias de ProductoForestal
            for especie, producto, volumen in zip(especies, productos, volumenes):
                ProductoForestal.objects.create(
                    especie_id=especie,
                    producto_id=producto,
                    volumen=volumen
                )
                
            messages.success(request, "Se ha creado el Acta Con exito!!")
            return redirect(list)
        else:
            messages.error(request,form.errors)

    form = ActaForm()
    context= {"form": form}
    return render(request, "formulario.html", context)

#forms.py

class ProductoForestalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductoForestal
        fields = ['especie', 'producto', 'volumen']
        

class ActaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    fecha = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=DateTimePicker(
            options={
                'useCurrent': True,
            },
            attrs={
                'append': 'fa-solid fa-calendar', 'icon_toggle': True,
                'size' : 'small',
            }
        ),
    )

    detalle = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )

    observacion = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Textarea
    )
    
    especie = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Especie.objects.all(), 
            required=False,
        )

    producto = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Producto.objects.all(), 
            required=False
        )

    volumen = forms.FloatField()
 
    class Meta:
        model = Acta
        fields = ["fecha","descripcion", "coordenada", "detalle", "observacion", "deposito", "depositario", "departamento", "distrito", "localidad", "especie", "producto", "volumen", "archivo"]



mi idea es que el formulario guarde los varios campos de especie producto volumen por cada acta de tal manera que cada acta pueda ser mas dinamica con los datos
Si alguien a tenido algun problema similar o puedan darme una mano

Leyendo la documentacion me di cuenta que django tiene una funcion especial para guardar formulario many to many
if request.method == "POST":
        form = ActaForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            acta_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            acta_instance.codigo_id = codigo[0]['id']
            acta_instance.group_id = grupo
            acta_instance.numero = num + 1
            acta_instance.funcionario = nombre
            acta_instance.save()
            form.save_m2m()  <---- linea agregada

```

